# Computing the permanent with polylog size matrices

Tags: complexity-classes, counting-complexity, permanent, polynomial-hierarchy

The complexity of computing the permanent of a $l\times l$ binary matrix is known to be $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete, from the famous result of [Valiant](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900446), where $l = \Theta(n)$.

We know that the problem is not in $\mathsf{P}$, unless $l = \mathcal{O}(\log_2 n)$. What can we say about the complexity of the problem when $l = \mathcal{o}(n)$ as well as $\log_2 n = \mathcal{o}(l)$ ? For example, if $l = \text{polylog}(n)$ ?

Does the problem remain $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete ? Or is it complete for a class in some level of the polynomial hierarchy ?

Comment: I think you mean Valiant, not Vazirani.

Comment: So your input is a polylog-sized description of a matrix plus some padding to make the input length n? If so, we can use the exponential time algorithm for the permanent to compute it in quasi-polynomial time (in n), so it's certainly not hard for NP (or any superset, such as #P) unless ETH fails.

Comment: ${\bf \#P}$ complete under Turing reductions.

Comment: @TayfunPay Could you kindly tell me why ? A citation would be great.

Comment: This one might be a related question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20510/variant-of-todas-theorem-for-intermediate-levels-of-the-polynomial-hierarchy