# Weight enumerator and levels of polynomial hierarchy

Tags: reference-request, counting-complexity, coding-theory, polynomial-hierarchy

Let $A_i$ be the number of codewords in a binary linear code $\mathcal{C}$ of weight $i$. It is known that:

1. $A_k$ is in $P$, where $k = \mathcal{O}(\log_2 n)$.
2. $A_{n}$ is in $\#P-Complete$, equivalently, computing $A_{n}$ is hard for $PH$, under polytime Turing reductions. See [here](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/66/57/82/PDF/BRIQUEL_IrA_nA_e_2011_ThA_se.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0304044.pdf).

What about the computational hardness of $A_{i}$ where $i = polylog(n)$ ? Are there results of the type: $A_{\lceil \log_{2}^{k}n \rceil} \in \Sigma^{P}_{k-1}$ ?

This question may be related to [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20485/computing-the-permanent-with-polylog-size-matrices) stack exchange question.