# Variant of Toda's theorem for intermediate levels of the polynomial hierarchy

Tags: reference-request, sat, counting-complexity, polynomial-hierarchy

Is there a version of Toda's theorem for intermediate levels of the polynomial hierarchy ? More precisely, is there any variant of the Toda's theorem that states:

Let $\# wSAT$ be the number of satisfying assignments to a boolean formula, where $(\log_2 n)^w$ variables (out of $n$) are assigned to TRUE.

> $\bigcup_{i=1}^k \Sigma^P_k \subseteq P^{\# wSAT}$ ?

If something of this form is known, a reference would greatly help.